# Rewrite URL to get contents from sub-directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have edited my `/etc/hosts` file to link `domain.com` to my localhost. Now when I visited `domain.com` I want it to get the site contents from `domain.com/site/` but only using the URL `domain.com` thus removing `site/` from the URL.

I have done this once before, so I know it's possible, but I lost the code. Can someone please assist me? `.htaccess` scripting is not my strong. Apologies if this is a duplicate of something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this working with the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)your_directory 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ your_directory/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^((?!site/).*)$ site/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to get contents from site when I go to domain.com

Comment: ok comment out both `RewriteCond` and retry. btw what is location of this .htaccess? Inside `ste` or a level above?

Comment: Hmm that's buggy since that will also block `/abcd/site` not just `/site/`, let me provide a more correct version here.

Comment: This is only for local development of a Wordpress site using the actual site URL.

Comment: Actually if you have WP in site folder then none of the solutions week work.